# J Factory::getUser() returning 0 id in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I am using an ajax page in a module to save data. In that when I used `JFactory::getUser()` I'm getting the result as

```
JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [username] => 
    [email] => 
    [password] => 
    [password_clear] => 
    [usertype] => 
    [block] => 
    [sendEmail] => 0
    [registerDate] => 
    [lastvisitDate] => 
    [activation] => 
    [params] => 
    [groups] => Array()

[guest] => 1
[lastResetTime] => 
[resetCount] => 
[_params:protected] => JRegistry Object
    (
        [data:protected] => stdClass Object ()

    )

[_authGroups:protected] => 
[_authLevels:protected] => 
[_authActions:protected] => 
[_errorMsg:protected] => 
[_errors:protected] => Array()

[aid] => 0
```

As have logged in before running this code, why is this still returning 0 user id. Can any one help me on this....

Comment: If you're logged as admin, I believe this is normal

Comment: You're right, 0 is when the user is not found. Indeed you get guest = 1, so Joomla thinks you're not logged in at all. Check you're really logged in... Maybe in the script you're executing you didn't start the session (I mean referenced all the files to start the Joomla environment)

Comment: Bgi, If I'm logged in as admin, then I should get the administrator id.Isn't it like that ? or am I wrong ?

Comment: But actually I am logged in..I just printed it in the default.php page of the module and it works fine..But in the ajax page I'm geting like this..

Comment: It might be because your Ajax request is not sending the Cookie header (identifying the session)

Comment: ajax request not sending cookie header issue occurs when the requested url is on some other domain.Isn't it ?
Is there some other reasons also for this ??

Comment: I suspect that you are not going through a proper Joomla URL/controller with your AJAX. Please post the AJAX url you are calling.

Answer (score 2):

The response you are getting from `JFactory::getUser()` is either the current JUser-object (related to your session) oder an empty JUser-object for guests. 
So in your case you are either not logged in or not loading Joomla properly.

The only php-files you should speak to are `index.php` and `administrator/index.php`, which are loading all necessary files and do what you want. (If you are using some CLI scripts you may have other options)

You can find more informations about Ajax on [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, it turned out to be a problem with the cookie domain, I was logged into the site using the domain example.com but accessing the AJAX URL using www.example.com. Just changing the domains so that they matched solved the problem.

In my experience

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->id;
```

will always return a positve user id if the user is logged in, regardless of whether they are an admin user or not, and 0 if they are not logged in. So if you are getting 0 when you think that you are logged in, it has to be a cookie problem of some sort, or the Joomla session is not correctly started, eg by not accessing the site through index.php.